# Does my app show ads on android 2.2 if i used android Project Build Target 4.0?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-ndk

When I'm trying to use GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.0.0 under android Project Build Target 2.2 an error raised "The android:configChanges value of the com.google.ads.AdActivity must include screenSize."
 I changed the android Project Build Target to 4.0 and added 
android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"             android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" 
it works fine
android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="14"

So, will the ads be shown on android 2.2 or previous?
and Could my app installed on android 2.2 or previous?

Answer (score 0):

`minSdkVersion="8"` means that it is compatible with everything down to [API Level](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html) 8 which is 2.2

So your app does not run on devices that have 2.1 or lower and it should run and display adds on everything that has at least 2.2

`android:targetSdkVersion="14"` means that you have tested you app and declare it compatible with up to version 14 (4.0.2). Android will disable some compatibility options and you should check if your app actually runs on that version.

Comment: Thanks zapl, but i tested it on my emulator 2.2 and no ads displayed,

Comment: did you add the internet permission?

Comment: Sorry, can't help you here. Maybe it's the emulator or AdMob detects that you are using the emulator and does not show ads.